# [PM2][WARN] Environment [production] is not defined in process file - while using pm2 static serve by ecosystem.config.js

Tags: single-page-application, pm2, npm-build

Using PM2 as server management, I used `pm2 serve` in ecosystem.config.js for serving my react app

Here is my ecosystem.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my-app",
      script: "serve",
      instances: "1",
      watch: false,
      exec_mode: "cluster",
      restart_delay: "5000",
      listen_timeout: 50000,
      kill_timeout: 5000,
      log_date_format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
  env:{
       NODE_ENV: "production",
       PM2_SERVE_PATH: 'build',
       PM2_SERVE_PORT: 3000,
    },
    },
  ],
};
```

The reason I wrote script as `serve` is for using `pm2 serve` as static server for index.html which was build.
Here is the [document](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/development-tools/) that I referenced.

But PM2 cannot find my `.env.production` file saying
`Environment [production] is not defined in process file`.

Is there other ways to set env process file for production?
Also I find out  running the app in port 3000 only works in `PM2_SERVE_PORT: 3000` when I use `script: serve`.

Another way doesn't make my app runs in port 3000.

So I need a way for using both values(NODE_ENV, PM2_SERVE_PORT, etc) in ecosystem.config.js settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following error happens if there is no `env_production` defined in your app in `ecosystem.config.js` but you are running pm2 like `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production`:

```bash
Environment [production] is not defined in process file
```

In my case I have the following for my sveltekit app:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
      name: "service:name",
      script: "./build/index.js",
      error_file: "./storage/log/error.log",
      out_file: "./storage/log/app.log",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
        PORT: 3000,
        ORIGIN: "http://localhost:3000",
        BODY_SIZE_LIMIT: 0
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        PORT: 3000,
        ORIGIN: "https://my-sample-domain.com",
        BODY_SIZE_LIMIT: 0
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

Running `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` will default to using the `env` property when setting variables. In this case it uses the following:

```js
env: {
  NODE_ENV: 'development',
  PORT: 3000,
  ORIGIN: "http://localhost:3000",
  BODY_SIZE_LIMIT: 0
},
```

Meanwhile, running `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production` will make pm2 look for `env_production` key in the app config. No need to create a separate file for production config, just add `env_production` property and define the production settings there then run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production`.

Documentation about [Switching environments in PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/).